# Подскажите SQL запрос - group by?

Tags: sql, mysql

У меня есть таблица:

```
source, duration

84991234567, 21

84991234568, 29

84951234569, 22
```

Где source - это исходящий номер телефона, duration - длительность вызова.

Мне нужно сгруппировать эти данные по коду города, т.е. получить следующее:

```
8499, 50

8495, 22
```

где второе число - это сумма duration.

Главный вопрос - как сгруппировать по коду города?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и так:

```
select left(source,4), sum(duration)
from table
group by left(source,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `SUBSTRING()`, и сделайте запрос с подзапросом. В итоге будет что-то вроде (мог ошибиться, т.к. пишу без проверки):

```
SELECT
  city_code,
  SUM(duration) 
FROM
  (SELECT
     SUBSTRING(source, 1, 4) city_code, duration
   FROM
     your_table)
GROUP BY
  city_code;
```

Comment: Спасибо за рабочий вариант и за напоминание о SUBSTRING, но вариант с LEFT и без вложенного запроса мне показался лучше.